# Removing a filename with two extensions

Tags: batch-rename

I have many audio files with the extensions ".lossy.cue" and ".lossy.wav" and would like to remove the ".lossy" part.  It seems to me the commands would be

```
ren "*.lossy.cue" "*.cue"
ren "*.lossy.wav" "*.wav"
```

but that has no effect.  I know I can do it in four steps like so:

```
ren *.cue *.
ren *.lossy *.cue
ren *.wav *.
ren *.lossy *.wav
```

but then I have to move any other files in the folder with the ".cue" or ".wav" extensions first.  Is there a simple way to remove this specific string in the filename without resorting to PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
ren *.lossy.wav *.
ren *.lossy *.wav
ren *.lossy.cue *.
ren *.lossy
```

Also, more information on the ren command:
https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards